# Winforms data binding: need to know when my data gets saved

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I can't believe I haven't run into this issue before: I have a data bound form and before the user navigates to another record I want to save some additional data from non-bound controls in addition to the bound data. The only event I can find is BindingManagerBase.PositionChanged but this seems to happen after the current record has changed. 
Is there a way to get an event when the data has just been saved but before the binding has moved to the new record?

Comment: Details, please! What are you binding to? What makes you think your data are ever saved?

Comment: I am using an object data source. The data from the bound controls get saved to the data source. Navigation gets done with a binding navigator and also a grid control that serves as list.
What I need now is a way to do some additional processing right before the binding moves to another object.

I guess I could intercept all buttons on the navigator and also when the grid changes its position but it would be much easier if I had an event that gets triggered right BEFORE the position changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at implementing a ListChangedEventHandler to detect when your list changes?  The list seems to raise an event of type Reset when the list position changes (assuming your data is in a BindingList<>).